# How to get all objects's attributes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with `Yt::Video` from [`yt` gem](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt). I have a model class `Video`,  which has lots of properties. I want to save all values of a `video` object's properties to a file in json, without mentioning the particular properties one by one.

I can't use `to_json` because of `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)` error.

I'd appreciate any thoughts about a better way of doing that.

***UPDATE***
Finally, thanks to Mr. Palma and D-side clues and especially to sawa's answer I figured out why stack was so deep.
It was happenning because Video model had Auth object as attribute which had Video object as child ... [Here comes endless cycle]

Comment: Doesn't `oject.attributes.to_json` work?

Comment: Have you tried `.as_json` method ?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Got: *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `attributes' for Yt::Models::Video:Class
Did you mean?  has_attribute

Comment: @Snoobie I get the same 'stack level too deep' error

Comment: @AlexanderGorg call `attributes` on **instance** of the model, not a class. And "stack level too deep" may need debugging, there is unbounded recursion somewhere.

Comment: I don't know what kind of object you're working with, could you explain?

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you very much, @Sebastian Palma!

Comment: @D-side Yes, I think you're right. I guess that's because Yt converts an answer from youtube in json format to model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties, or attributes is a notion in Rails. Without it, is is not clear what you mean by them.

If you mean by properties the instance variables defined for the class, and given that you have your `to_json` defined on basic object types, then you can define something like:

```
class Video
  def to json
    instance_variables.each_with_object({}) do |k, h|
      h[k] = instance_variable_get("@#{k}")
    end.to_json
  end
end
```